# Working form without action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to do html form without action. It must:

1) Remember input data as normal form do.

2) Doesn't reload page

I tried:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" id="simple-form">
```

But on

```
$('#simple-form').submit();
```

form didn't remember input data.
Normal form

```
<form action="#" id="simple-form">
```

reloads page but also remembers input data.

**Does exist another way to remember  data without forms with javascript?**

**Update #1:**

```
event.preventDefault(); // onsubmit event prevert
```

Doesn't work same because it's preventing not only reload of page but also saving of data (autocomplete).

Comment: Just don't submit it... choose any action you wish, even google URL would be ok, and simply add an onsubmit event that eventually returns false and that's it I guess.

Comment: How about considering using cookies like the plugin [jCookie](http://www.webmuse.co.uk/projects/jcookie-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: add onsubmit event having return type false. Serialize the form data using formname.serielize (see jQuery serielize ) and send the data through ajax to a php page to save the data to session. when you are reloading the page, simply put the session variable in form

Comment: What's the point in a form that doesn't post anything anywhere?

Comment: Without reload means not sending the form. Not sending the form means keeping the data in fields. If you want to send the data, use then ajax.

Comment: This is needed only for remembering input data (with standart browser-choose-popup of last inputed strings)

Answer (score 1):

With javascript

```
var form = document.getElementById("simple-form")
form.onsubmit = function (event) { event.preventDefault() }

if(localStorage){
    var textfield = document.getElementById("yourTextfield");
    var data = localStorage.getItem("yourTextfield");
    if(data){
       textfield.value = JSON.parse(data);
    }
    textfield.onkeydown = function(){
         localStorage.setItem("yourTextfield",JSON.stringify(textfield.value));
   }
}
```

ok alternative solution with history object

```
var data = history.state.textfieldName;
if(data){
    textfield.value = data;
}
textfield.onkeydown = function(){
    history.state.textfieldName = textfield.value;
}
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(); - prevents page reloading and also prevents save of data (autocomplete).

Comment: updated, if you need a fallback for old browsers/disabled cookies you could also save it in browsing history. (I actually don't how the support of manipulating the browsing history is in old browsers, I still have to read into it myself.)

Comment: Self-implement local storage is looking like good way to overcome this autocomplete problem. Will see, may be someone know more elegant way.

Comment: I actually tested it and it does save the data with the `preventDefault()` method. At least if you mean by saving the data that it gets preserved if you navigate away and back to the site.

Comment: I didn't test storage method, but with preventDefault() only form didn't save autocomplete info when i reloaded page/back on site (but asked about saving password input in history) [tested in chrome, may be in other browsers this can be different].